# ajax response data is undefined always

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I trying to get data from data base via ajax code. PHP code works well but ajax reponse always is undefined. I tried json bat resuls is same.
here are codes:

```
    var email = $('#email').val();

    function getAjax(p, m) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../lib/checkmail.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {val : p, column : m},
            success: function (data) {
                return data.toString();
            }
        });
    }
    if (email.length > 0){

        alert(getAjax(email, 'youremail'));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: may be issue in checkmail.php file

Comment: Where is your lib folder placed ? Is it placed one level before the file that you are calling the AJAX from ? Based on your screenshot I think you are getting a Notice. Try accessing the same thing in Firefox. Google developer tools will not always give you the complete response. I think if you solve the Notice issue then Your issue will be resolved as well.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax call works asynchroneously. So when you call `getAjax(p, m)` if will start to get the url, which takes time, but the function returns immediately. Only after the url has been retrieve will the `success` function of the ajax call be executed. So what you could test is this:

```
var email = $('#email').val();

function getAjax(p, m) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../lib/checkmail.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {val : p, column : m},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.toString());
        }
    });
}
if (email.length > 0){

    getAjax(email, 'youremail');
}
```

this should give you an alert with the correct response.

Another, obvious, problem is, which you might now realize, that `getAjax(p, m)` does not return a value, ever. The `return` belongs to the `success` function. Hence the return value of `getAjax(p, m)` will always be 'undefined'.

You will have to learn how to work with an event driven asynchroneous programming language. Better use a good book, or course.